# IIS 6 URL rewrite to lowercase urls

Tags: iis-6, url-rewriting

Currently we are using Managed Fusion Rewriter to handle rewrites, however, we have been unable to determine a way to have it do a rewrite to urls all lowercase. Unfortunately, upgrading to IIS 7 isn't an option right now. Does anyone have any experience utilizing another rewrite module to handle rewriting to lowercase urls.

Comment: Why exactly does it matter? Windows isn't a case sensitive environment...

Answer (score 0):

Managed Fusion Rewriter uses the same syntax as Apache's mod_rewrite module, which I would presume means that you can use mod_rewrite's rules, as well.

Try the lowercase URL rule located [here](http://www.chrisabernethy.com/force-lower-case-urls-with-mod_rewrite/).

The pertinent bits are:

```
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```